# Prevent unallowed pasting into text-input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I'm trying to prevent the user from pasting unallowed text into an input field. The Input is a randomly generated 8 digit Code, that contains letters and numbers.

But I don't want the user to paste any text that contains other characters.

**my input field:**

```
<input type='text' id='form-code-field' name='code' maxlength='8'>
```

**Note:**

I'm not looking for something like the `readonly` attribute, because the user still has to input alphanumeric text into the field.

Comment: what about making it `read-only`?

Comment: so you mean something like this? `<input type='text' id='form-code-field' name='code' maxlength='8' readonly>`

Comment: Sorry then, its not what I'm looking for, i dont want the user to paste anything, but he still has to write something in it

Comment: Then pls update your question. Also you can try `keycode` to restrict `ctrl+v` when the input text is in focus.

Comment: Looks like question is too complicated. Why not just say: "User is able to enter only letters & digits" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test value input using a regex on `input` event:

```js
$('#form-code-field').on('input', function(){
    if(!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(this.value)) this.value = $(this).data('oldValue') || "";
    else $(this).data('oldValue', this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='form-code-field' name='code' maxlength='8'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I run the first code, i can only input numbers, but i would like to input also letters. Can you change the code so it works as said? or tell me how to change the regex :-)

Comment: Regex could be `/^[a-z0-9]+$/i` or use `\w` to get all valid alpha numeric character, e.g to allow `_` too

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 browsers you can also do this, and no script required:

```
<input type='text' name='code' maxlength='8' pattern="^[a-z0-9]+$" title="a-z0-9">
```

This will not stop someone from write non valid characters, the pattern will be evaluated on submit and will abort the submit with a message if not matched.

Update

I added a plain javascript version for those who don't use jQuery, which works globally on a form. Just set the "pattern" on a input field and it kicks in.

The script also works on input on non HTML5 browsers.

A "safety" note:

As a client side evaluation, this by no means is 100% safe to just store server side, you *always* need to check whats posted before doing anything with it.

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  
    if (e.target.pattern && e.target.pattern.length > 0) {
        var regex = new RegExp(e.target.pattern,"i");
        if(!regex.test(e.target.value)) {
            if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
                e.target.value = e.target.getAttribute('data-old-value') || "";
            } else {
                e.target.setAttribute('data-old-value', "");
            }
        } else {
            e.target.setAttribute('data-old-value', e.target.value);
        }
    }
  
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="form">

  Only alphanum (max 8): <input type='text' id='form-code-field' name='code' maxlength='8' pattern="^[a-z0-9]+$" title="a-z0-9"><br /><br />

  Any character (max 5): <input type='text' id='form-code-field' name='code' maxlength='5' ><br />

</form>
```

Comment: You can, but it will prevent nothing. Please read the question again.

Comment: Is this safe? I mean, anyone who visits my Site "could" edit the pattern so it accepts specialchars again, couldn't he?

Comment: It is as safe as any other client side method, as any user can "copy the form" and send it to your server without any jQuery, patterns, etc., so you need to check this again, server side, to be 100% sure the input is accurate.

Comment: @skobaljic Actually added a fully "asked for" update.

Comment: Think there is no need to keep old value and for that you could use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). I would rather keep it simple [using match regex](http://jsfiddle.net/0c0jm1e5/1/).

Comment: @skobaljic I used attribute for older browser support, like IE8,9,10, but simple is good. When one delete a char in the middle, your fiddle puts caret at the end evey time. Why's that?

Comment: Probably because you are not using Firefox haha, guess it sets new value on input mate.

Comment: @skobaljic LOL (using Chrome) ... ok, so a temp storage in dataset or attribute overcomes that then.

Comment: I think your original answer was sufficient, adding any script would have sense only in specific occasions, for example if you work on betting app and user must enter "1", "2" or "X" or some combination. Browser would worn about invalid field and anyhow you need to do server-side validation.

Comment: @skobaljic I thought so, though it was you that wrote _You can, but it will prevent nothing. Please read the question again_, which made me give it a second thought ..  remember :)